# Sharing scope between nested directives and controllers in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have created a controller and directive in my angular application defined as following:

```
app.controller('CrudCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.isLoading = true;

    $scope.pageChanged = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/repository'+$scope.repository.path,
            params: {
                size: 3,
                page: $scope.currentPage
            }
        }).
            success(function (data, status){
                $scope.rowCollection = data._embedded['rest-original-product'];
                $scope.totalPages = data.page.totalPages;
                $scope.currentPage = data.page.number + 1;
                $scope.totalElements = data.page.totalElements;
                $scope.pageSize = data.page.size;
                $scope.isLoading = false;
                $scope.numPages = 5;
            }).
            error(function (data, status){
                log.error("Error");
            });
    };


    $scope.$watch('repository', function(newVal, oldVal){
        if(newVal!=null && oldVal!=newVal ){

        }
    });


}]);
app.directive('crud', ['$resource', 'CrudConstant', '$http', function($resource, CrudConstant, $http) {
    return {
        //scope:{},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.repository = CrudConstant[attrs.repository];

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/repository'+scope.repository.path,
                params: {
                    size: 3
                }
            }).
                success(function (data, status){
                    scope.rowCollection = data._embedded['rest-original-product'];
                    scope.totalPages = data.page.totalPages;
                    scope.currentPage = data.page.number + 1;
                    scope.totalElements = data.page.totalElements;
                    scope.pageSize = data.page.size;
                    scope.isLoading = false;
                    scope.numPages = 5;
                }).
                error(function (data, status){
                    log.error("Error");
                });


        },
        templateUrl: 'tpl/app/crud/crud.html'
    };
}]);
app.directive('table', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        },
        templateUrl: 'tpl/app/crud/table.html'
    };
}]);
```

while the structure is the following:

```
<div ui-view class="fade-in-up" ng-controller="CrudCtrl">
    <crud repository="originalProduct">

    </crud>
</div>
```

where here goes crud template:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 m-b-xs">
    <pagination
            total-items="totalElements"
            items-per-page="pageSize"
            ng-change="pageChanged()"
            ng-model="currentPage"
            max-size="5"
            class="pagination-sm m-t-none m-b"
            boundary-links="true"
            rotate="false"
            num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
</div>
<div>{{rowCollection}}</div>
```

When I launch the application rest call is executed correctly and data are shown as expected (rowCollection shows correct data), but when I click on the pagination button which calls pageChanged() function, the controller has not $scope.repository property set. What seems to be happening is that controller is not binded/linked to the scope defined in the directive.

I also tried to add scope.$apply() at the end od the link function in the directive but I get error in that case: 
"Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress".

Comment: are you using `isolated` scope? seems like commented for some reason or is there?

Comment: You need to look at `require: '^'` option of directive

Answer (score 0):

I have not read too much but there is mistake in your first line `app.controller('CrudCtrl', ['$scope', 'schemaForm', '$http', function($scope, $http)` should be `app.controller('CrudCtrl', ['$scope', 'schemaForm', '$http', function($scope, schemaForm, $http)`

Comment: I'm not sure this is the solution of the problem. I modified it and I still get the same error.

Comment: Just changed the description in order to dont make confusion as schemaForm dependency is not necessary